# Can users play simultaneously from one copy of Civilization V?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I read in an ad for Civilization 5 that it allows installation on 5 different computers.  Does that mean I can install it on my kid's computer and mine, and then we can *simultaneously play*, or even in versus, or can only one install play the game at a time?

I've been looking around for any reference to the 5 different installations and can't find anything beyond the original ad.  In the ad it didn't mention how many simultaneous players you could have, just installations.

Comment: Do you have a link to the ad? Or a quote, might help.

Comment: It was in Popular Science.  I don't see an online copy of it on their website.  I'll see if I can find the original magazine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Civilization 5 is designed to work with Valve's [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) platform.

This will allow you to install the game on **any number of computers**, but **requires you to log-in with steam to play**. Since only one steam account can be logged in at once this restricts you to playing the game on **only one computer simultaneously**.

The exception is that you can run Steam in **'offline mode'** to play the game exclusively in single player mode, in which case multiple computers could each play 'offline' at the same time. 
<strike>From what I understand it is **not possible to play a LAN game** this way, you would need two copies of the game (and two steam accounts)</strike>. **Apparently it IS possible to play on LAN in offline mode.** If so, this would allow you to play with your son with a single copy of the game.

This would seem to be a deliberate Steam design choice, for better or worse.

I'm not sure why an ad would specify the number **5**, since Steam would not limit the number of installations at all, and only one account could play online at a time.

Comment: You can in fact play LAN while in offline mode, since LAN play isn't handled by Steam in any situation. You cannot play online with Steam offline.

Comment: @Arda Xi: Thanks for that, I have never tried playing Civ5 multiplayer yet.

Comment: That's great to know for those of us that haven't purchased it yet for a very similar reason (local LAN play with my wife -- we'd rather not buy two copies for something that might only happen once or twice a year).

Comment: @libyrdie: Try to get an official confirmation on this before you buy it. I have only heard it from the comment above, and have not tried it myself.

Comment: @AKusete - [Here you go](http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showthread.php?p=944015#post944015). (Scroll down a bit.)

Answer (score 2):

Seeings how it would be tied to your steam account, and your steam account can only be logged into one computer at a time, I do not believe you can play on multiple computers with one installation.  Instead, you would need to gift another copy to your son's steam account, and play together in that way.  I believe the 5 different computers just refers to the number of machines that can have the game installed on it, not the number of copies that can be played at once.